# uicollectionview not showing cells swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I got my data from a url as `json` string. in my codes, `titles` variable is an array of my `url` images.

```
private let reuseIdentifier = "cell_supporters"

class SupportersCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {
    var ids             = [String]()
    var titles          = [String]()

    @IBOutlet var collection_supporters: UICollectionView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        collection_supporters.delegate = self

        // Register cell classes
        self.collectionView!.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        getSupporters()
    }

    // MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource

//    override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
//        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
//        return 1
//    }


    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of items
        return self.titles.count
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! SupportersCollectionViewCell

        print("Hello collectionView")

        let url_img = URL(string: self.titles[indexPath.row])!

        print(url_img)
        cell.img_logo.af_setImage(
            withURL: url_img
        )

        return cell
    }

    func getSupporters() {
        RestApiManager.sharedInstance.getSupporters { (json: JSON) in
            if let results = json.array {
                for entry in results {
                    // print(entry["title"])
                    //self.ids.append(entry["id"].string!)
                    self.titles.append(entry["title"].string!)
                }

                print(self.titles.count)

                DispatchQueue.main.async{
                    self.collection_supporters.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

in my code :

```
print(self.titles.count) // it shows 5
```

but:

```
print("Hello collectionView") // not show anything !
```

Comment: What is the difference between `self.collection_supporters` and `self.collectionView` aren't mixing 2 UICollectionView? But your issue should be `collection_supporters.datasource` is set to `self` (in InterfaceBuilder at least, because it isn't done by the code you provided).

Answer (score 4):

If you're using the default `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` class for the layout you can try implementing the delegate method that returns the size of each item in the `collectionView`. The `UICollectionView` doesn't call the `cellForItemAt` dataSource method at all if it doesn't have the size information or if they're zero.

Try adding this:

```
extension SupportersCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: 40, height: 40) // Return any non-zero size here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Dont register cell classes. Delete following line from viewDidLoad function :

```
 self.collectionView!.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
```

Comment: I dunno why this answer has -1 but it helped me!

Comment: same here not clear how it helped, why to delete this line, why to not register?

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in your `ViewDidLoad()` method:

```
self.collectionView!.delegate = self
```

Comment: This was a guess because you are assigning the `delegate` to the `collection_supporters` but you are registering the cell to `self.collectionView`. Maybe try registering the cell to `collection_supporters` instead?

Comment: And why are you downvoting my answer since it's not a bad practice to do this? I just tried to help based on the code you provided .. @S.M_Emamian

Comment: Although it didn't solve your particular problem this would have indeed been an issue

Answer (score 0):

Change it to this:

```
private let reuseIdentifier = "cell_supporters"

class SupportersCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {
    var ids             = [String]()
    var titles          = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Register cell classes
        self.collectionView!.register(SupportersCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        getSupporters()
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of items
        return self.titles.count
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! SupportersCollectionViewCell

        print("Hello collectionView")

        let url_img = URL(string: self.titles[indexPath.row])!

        print(url_img)
        cell.img_logo.af_setImage(
            withURL: url_img
        )

        return cell
    }

    func getSupporters() {
        RestApiManager.sharedInstance.getSupporters { (json: JSON) in
            if let results = json.array {
                for entry in results {
                    // print(entry["title"])
                    //self.ids.append(entry["id"].string!)
                    self.titles.append(entry["title"].string!)
                }

                print(self.titles.count)

                DispatchQueue.main.async{
                    self.collectionView!.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

First, you don't required this:

```
@IBOutlet var collection_supporters: UICollectionView!
```

Because your view controller is inherited from UICollectionViewController

Also I changed the register of the UICollectionViewCell class to this so it won't crash when you the cells are created:

```
self.collectionView!.register(SupportersCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
```